# Compile Solr source code into WAR

Tags: linux, compiling, ant

I'm trying to compile Solr 4.10.4 (on Ubuntu 14.04) from source so that I can make use of a patch. I've applied the patch, and successfully compiled the source code. But where do I find the compiled Solr WAR file? When you download the binary Solr distribution, it exists under `dist/solr-<version>.war`. No `dist` directory and no `solr-<version>.war` exists anywhere under the base source directory, `solr`, `solr/build`, `lucene`, or `lucene/build`. I must be missing something simple.

After following the instructions from the *README.txt* and an error about missing Ivy as a dependency, I ran the following to compile Solr:

```
ant ivy-bootstrap
ant compile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you've compiled Solr, you must go to the `solr/` directory, and run the ant command *dist*  in order to build the JARs:

```
ant dist
```

The Solr WAR file will now be present at `solr/dist/solr-<version>.war`.

Comment: c.f. https://wiki.apache.org/solr/HowToCompileSolr

Comment: @RodneyGitzel Thanks, I skipped that guide before because it was labelled for Windows.